# (DB/SQL) Performance-oriented way to manage map coordinates data

Tags: sql, database, database-performance

I have a function that lets users either to create a new spot/marker on a map using the usual Latitude & Longitude paired value or to modify any existing spots. And obviously these spots will need to be saved to a table.

**Scenario**: The table currently holds six set of coordinates, which are initially retrieved on a map. Let's say two of the existing spots are modified, three of them are removed, and finally, four new spots are added to the map.

Now, being a novice SQL user, I could think of only two approaches for writing the resulting coordinates back to the database as follows:

1. Remove all existing data in the table first, then grab everything that's left on the map and iterate through them and simply create each set of coordinates.
2. Update the data for the modified spots. Delete only the ones that are actually removed by user. Create new records for all new spots.

For this simplistic scenario, I'd think that option #1 requires one DELETE query, and six CREATE queries, which result in a total of seven queries that need to be executed. On the other hand, option #2 requires three DELETE queries, two UPDATE queries, and four CREATE queries, which comes to a total of nine queries.

The whole point of posting this question is because I'm not sure what kind of performance advantage or disadvantage I should expect for either approach when the dataset becomes considerably large. Is either one of the two approaches inherently better than the other due to other reasons than the total number of required queries? What's the conventional way of dealing with a scenario similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is not going to be feasible as you scale up. What if client A modifies 3 points and your table contains 3 trillion points? You will truncate the entire table and then insert all 2.9 trillion points back in? If you had client B that wants to view the map during that time, they'll have to wait a while for the table to come back up. Besides that, there is much higher risk when you talk about wiping a table.
2. Is more traditional, safer, and easier to scale.

You can test both of these easily with test data, and you'll be able to observe the difference

Note: It's not the number of queries that determines performance. It's what those queries are attempting to do, what your schema is designed for, and what DBMS you're using. Also take a look at R-trees. They're very important for efficient spatial queries. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

Comment: Makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

well assuming you are using some type of the clustered index, deleting many the entries with (1) could cause fragmentation. you could also look closer into "fill factor" setting of your clustered index, depending on how many new entries you expect, so that there will be enough "free slots". your database should be decently fast then.